# Scalable width on a nav bar

Tags: css, width

I have a website that is responsive and when you scale the site down. The site looks good, but if you scroll to the right there is a blank space because the nav-bar is 1000px wide.

When the site is sclaed down to tablet or phone the nav folds into a special mobile nav but the div from the larger site still remains.

My question is what can I do to make that div scale down with the rest of the site?

You'll see what I mean if you look at the site.

[Glacialpace.com](http://glacialpace.com)

Answer (score 0):

use % for the navbar unit instead of pixels this will allow it to also scale down with the site. also remember to add  auto margin to the right and left of the navbar